# Sort datatable without affecting rowstate

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I have a datagridview bound to a datatable.
The user makes changes to the rows, and can alter the column operationnumber, which sets the rowstate to modified.

Then, when I sort the datatable using a dataview, it sets all the rows to rowsstate added regardless of whether their position has changed as a result of the sorting.

```
 dv = New DataView(DGVTable, Nothing, "operationnumber ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
DGVTable = dv.totable()
```

If I sort the rows using datatable.select instead, it sets all the rows to rowstate modified

```
DGVTable = DGVTable.Select(Nothing, "operationnumber").CopyToDataTable
```

How can I preserve the rowstate and sort?  I'm happy for the rows to be set as modified if their position has changed as a result of the sort.

Comment: Can you not call GetChanges() prior to the sort?  Then you have your changes.

Comment: I want to use the rowstate when the user has finished all their editing and decides they are ready to save. But maybe I should make a note of the changes before the sort as you suggest.

Comment: The problem is you are making a new table when you sort.  You could try binding the data view directly...

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll do some research

Comment: `CopyToDataTable` creates a copy of the data in a new DataTable, so yes, they are going to be all new in that table.  You can apply a sort or a filter to the DataView without changing the rowstate(s)